# Cypress: export and import classes with module.exports

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, end-to-end, autotest

Hi how can I export and import a class to a test using module exports?

This is how I export with module.exports

```
module.exports = class ExampleClass {

}
```

How do I import this class to a test?

Answer (score 0):

You can import the class like this `Import ExampleClass from 'ExampleClass.js'`

Then in the spec file you would initialize the class something like this `const example = new ExampleClass;` Then you would have access to the class methods and such.